# Teradata: Parsing a string based on a delimiter, then returning distinct values found in parsed string

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have an existing database containing a column we can call "PACKAGES" with values concatenated to make a string, each row also contains a corresponding "ACCOUNT_ID" value.

```
Row 1: ACCOUNT_ID = 123, PACKAGES = 'AAA BBB CCC '
Row 2: ACCOUNT_ID = 456, PACKAGES = ' DDD DDD AAA BBB CCC CCC EEE'
Row 3: ACCOUNT_ID = 789, PACKAGES = 'FFF ZZZ QQQ QQQ'
```

I need to generate code that let's me delimit the packages field for each account so that 1) the code recognizes when a SPACE leads the characters like in Row 2, and 2) only shows distinct packages for the respective accounts even if the ACCOUNT_ID field isn't distinct in the resulting answer set.

```
ACCOUNT_ID | PACKAGES    
123        | AAA
123        | BBB
123        | CCC
456        | DDD
456        | AAA
456        | BBB
456        | CCC
456        | EEE
789        | FFF
789        | ZZZ
789        | QQQ
```

I tried using `REGEXP` in some sample code that I found online below, but I don't know where I can enter the table name from the database I'm using, and I don't know if I can replace my "PACKAGES" field with any of the codes below to get what I need.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (

    REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE ('SMART PHONES','MOTOROLA&MICROSOFT&GOOGLE&APPLE','&','C')

    RETURNS (OUTKEY VARCHAR(10), TOKEN_NDX INTEGER, TOKEN VARCHAR(10))

) AS T1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for regexp_split_to_table always drives me crazy.

```
select
*
from
table (regexp_split_to_table(<your db.table>.account_id,<your db.table>.packages, ' ','c')
returns   (account_Id integer, tok_num integer,package varchar(100))) as t
```

Which will give you:

```
account_Id  tok_num package
    123     1       AAA
    123     2       BBB
    123     3       CCC
```

To only get distinct values, you can run:

```
select
 distinct account_id,package
from
table (regexp_split_to_table(<your db.table>.account_id,<your db.table>.packages, ' ','c')
returns   (account_Id integer, tok_num integer,package varchar(100))) as t
order by account_id,package
```

**EDIT:**

After your comment about length being exceeded, I did a little digging. STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_STRING seems to be able to handle longer strings including clobs than REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_STRING (don't ask me why...). So, poaching a bit from @DNoeth, here's something to try:

```
with cte as (
select account_id,
cast(packages as clob)
from your_table)
SELECT
  DISTINCT account_Id, package
FROM TABLE (StrTok_Split_To_Table(cte.account_id,cte.packages, ' ')
     RETURNS (account_Id INTEGER, tok_num INTEGER,package VARCHAR(100))) AS t
```

I hacked together a huge (60k) string and tested this logic with it, it worked for me.  Note that casting to clob is required, otherwise you'll get the same error.

Comment: Hi, Andrew. I used the first statement you provided, replacing "your db" with my database name, "table" with my table name, and the actual column names. I also included a `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE` to shorten the query. I'm receiving a `SELECT Failed. [9134] Input exceeds the buffer size limit` error. Is there a way of escaping this error? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I think that means your input string (second argument, table.packages in my code) exceeds the maximum length supported by the function. How is that column defined?

Comment: See if the last edit works for you.  Borrowed a bit from @dnoeth.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Andrew'sanswer.

The easiest way to pass data to a Table Operator is using a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH cte AS
 ( -- whatever you need to prepare your data
   SELECT * FROM your_table 
 )
SELECT
  DISTINCT account_Id, package
FROM TABLE (RegExp_Split_To_Table(cte.account_id,cte.packages, ' ','c')
     RETURNS (account_Id INTEGER, tok_num INTEGER,package VARCHAR(100))) AS t
```

But in your case a RegEx is not needed, there's another UDF to split strings based on delimiters:

```
WITH cte AS
 ( -- whatever you need to prepare your data
   SELECT * FROM your_table 
 )
SELECT
  DISTINCT account_Id, package
FROM TABLE (StrTok_Split_To_Table(cte.account_id,cte.packages, ' ')
     RETURNS (account_Id INTEGER, tok_num INTEGER,package VARCHAR(100))) AS t
```

Comment: Is strtok_split_to_Table any better/more efficient/cheaper/whatever than regexp_split_to_table?

Comment: @Dnoeth Is there any way to achieve something similar but with multi character separator?

Comment: @GalalOuda: RegExp_Slit_To_Table should be able to handle this

Comment: Regexp_Split_To_Table exceeds buffer size limit